# What are the data disks used for?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I need to know the difference between the SSD disk and the data disk. According to this capture, this virtual machine has a hard disk ssd 16gb, and 4 disks data. But these 4 disks, how much do they have? Are they ssd? what are they for?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnTml.png)

Answer (score 3):

data disks can be ssd or not, depending on how you set them up. they are used to store data :)

amount of data disks you can attach depends on the vm sku. you dont always have to attach 4 data disks (or whatever vm supports, you can have 0 - VM SKU maximum data disks).
The 16gb ssd is local ssd (local to the host machine hosting your vm) attached to the VM (not OS disk). its a temporary drive - meaning it can go away when you reboot vm, so content will be lost and you will get a new temporary drive. it can be used to store throw away logs, for example, or temporary files. IO operations on this disk do not count towards IO limit and this drive is completely free (you pay for the VM SKU and it is part of that cost).

you can learn about data disk prices here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/. Storage prices do not take into account os or data disks. they just bill you for storage.

reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-managed-disk-portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-disk-ps

Comment: Hello again

But if I choose for example the option that I show in the image. It does not have SSD, but it does not indicate what type of hard drive I am going to add to this machine, so I do not know how to give a price to the client.

Comment: you always choose\define what storage you are using when creating vm, so you didnt notice it, that's it. also, you probably shouldn't sell something to somebody unless you understand what you are selling

Answer (score 0):

It means in addition to the OS disk, you can connect 4 data disks to the VM.
It does not mean there are 4 disks, just that you can add 4 if you want.

Comment: Hello again

But if I choose for example the option that I show in the image. It does not have SSD, but it does not indicate what type of hard drive I am going to add to this machine, so I do not know how to give a price to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should discuss the VM requirements with your client. Maybe he needs an additional data disk, maybe not.

The capture you posted, specifies that this VM can take up to 4 data disks. The price does not include them. Also, you should check the [Azure price calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to generate more accurate offers.